# Angular ng-options rendering twice for scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, webpack, ng-options

I'm running into a really weird situation using ng-options inside a directive. Ideally, I'm trying to render a list of the 50 US States, but I'm running into the issue no matter what I fill the array with. Basically It's rendering each select option twice, as if it went through the loop twice, I'm using Angular 1.6.3 and webpack:

### Directive:

```
    var ctrl = function($scope){

        // $scope.states_list = statesList
        $scope.states_list = [
            { abbr : 'A', name : 'Test A' },
            { abbr : 'B', name : 'Test B' },
            { abbr : 'C', name : 'Test C' },
        ]

        $scope.init = function(){
            // $scope.states_list = statesList
        }

    }


    var directive = function(){
      return {
        restrict : 'E',
        templateUrl : '/templates/forms/address',
            controller : ctrl,
            // transclude: true,
            // require: 'ngModel',
            replace : true,
            scope : {
                form : '=',
                address : '='
            }
      }
    }


    module.exports = function(app){
      app.directive('addressForm', directive)
    }
```

### Template:  (In Jade/Pug)

```
div(ng-init="init()")
    .row: .form-group.col-md-12(validate-field="form.name", error-message="Please enter a name")
        label.control-label Name
        input.form-control(name='name', placeholder='Name', type='text', required, ng-model="address.name")
    .row: .form-group.col-md-12(validate-field="form.address1", error-message="Please enter an address")
        label.control-label Address
        input.form-control(name='address1', placeholder='Address', type='text', required, ng-model="address.address1")
    .row: .form-group.col-md-12
        label.control-label Address2
        input.form-control(name='address2', placeholder='Address2', type='text', ng-model="address.address2")
    .row
        .form-group.col-md-6(validate-field="form.city",  error-message="Please enter a city")
            label.control-label City
            input.form-control(name='city', placeholder='City', type='text', required, ng-model="address.city")
        .form-group.col-md-3(validate-field="form.state", error-message="Please select a state")
            label.control-label State / Province
            select.form-control(name="state", ng-model="address.state", ng-options="st.abbr as st.name for st in states_list")
                option(value="") -- Select a State --
        .form-group.col-md-3(validate-field="form.postal_code",  error-message="Please enter a valid ZIP Code")
            label.control-label Postal/ZIP Code
            input.form-control(name='postal_code', placeholder='Postal/ZIP Code', type='text', required, ng-model="address.postal_code")
        input(type="hidden", name="country", value="US", ng-model="address.country")
```

### Results:

```
        <div ng-init="init()" address="delivery" form="ctrl.shipping_form" class="ng-isolate-scope">
            <div class="row">
                <div error-message="Please enter a name" class="form-group col-md-12 ng-scope" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.name.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.name.$invalid }" tooltip-trigger="'none'" uib-tooltip="Please enter a name" tooltip-is-open="form.name.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.name.$invalid">
                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required="required" ng-model="address.name" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div error-message="Please enter an address" class="form-group col-md-12 ng-scope" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.address1.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.address1.$invalid }" tooltip-trigger="'none'" uib-tooltip="Please enter an address" tooltip-is-open="form.address1.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.address1.$invalid">
                    <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                    <input name="address1" placeholder="Address" type="text" required="required" ng-model="address.address1" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label class="control-label">Address2</label>
                    <input name="address2" placeholder="Address2" type="text" ng-model="address.address2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div error-message="Please enter a city" class="form-group col-md-6 ng-scope" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.city.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.city.$invalid }" tooltip-trigger="'none'" uib-tooltip="Please enter a city" tooltip-is-open="form.city.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.city.$invalid">
                    <label class="control-label">City</label>
                    <input name="city" placeholder="City" type="text" required="required" ng-model="address.city" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                </div>
                <div error-message="Please select a state" class="form-group col-md-3 ng-scope" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.state.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.state.$invalid }" tooltip-trigger="'none'" uib-tooltip="Please select a state" tooltip-is-open="form.state.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.state.$invalid">
                    <label class="control-label">State / Province</label>
                    <select name="state" ng-model="address.state" ng-options="st.abbr as st.name for st in states_list" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
                        <option value="" class="" selected="selected">-- Select a State --</option>
                        <option label="Test A" value="string:A">Test A</option>
                        <option label="Test B" value="string:B">Test B</option>
                        <option label="Test C" value="string:C">Test C</option>
                        <option label="Test A" value="string:A">Test A</option>
                        <option label="Test B" value="string:B">Test B</option>
                        <option label="Test C" value="string:C">Test C</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div error-message="Please enter a valid ZIP Code" class="form-group col-md-3 ng-scope" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.postal_code.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.postal_code.$invalid }" tooltip-trigger="'none'" uib-tooltip="Please enter a valid ZIP Code" tooltip-is-open="form.postal_code.$dirty &amp;&amp; form.postal_code.$invalid">
                    <label class="control-label">Postal/ZIP Code</label>
                    <input name="postal_code" placeholder="Postal/ZIP Code" type="text" required="required" ng-model="address.postal_code" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="country" value="US" ng-model="address.country" autocomplete="off" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you provide a plunkr?

Comment: Tried to create a plunkr.. works just fine... Also, moving it outside of the directive works fine. Was hoping that someone knows about a bug or a workaround for a similar issue.. Right now I'm looking at rendering the HTML option tags manually, rather than through Angular...

Comment: I would say if the plunkr works fine and you copies the code exactly, perhaps there is a version mismatch issue between the libraries you are using.

Comment: Any luck with checking versions?

Comment: No, wanted to move on... I just manually added them to the HTML... :-/